# How to get substrings from a string after splitting the string with a special symbol and including the special symbol to the first substring?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split the string with semicolon into array of strings, but whenever it is splitting the string with semicolon I need to add that semicolon to the first splitting string. It is adding to the next splitting screen.

```
String sampleContent="hello ; hai ;  come fast ;";
            String SQLScripts[] = sampleContent.split("(?=\\;)",-1);
            System.out.println(" SQLSCript Length is:"+SQLScripts.length);
            for(int m=0;m<SQLScripts.length;m++){
                System.out.println("After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : "+SQLScripts[m]);
            }`
```

The output that I am expecting is:

```
 SQLSCript Length is:4
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : hello ;
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : hai ;
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : come fast ;
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
 SQLSCript Length is:4
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : hello 
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : ; hai 
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : ;  come fast 
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : ;
```

Comment: Use a look-*behind* instead of a look-*ahead*: `(?<=;)` (And no need to escape the `;`.)

Comment: Shouldn´t the length in your expected output be `3` instead of `4`?

Comment: @Biffen: Thank you very much your answer helped me a lot.Thank you dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this regex `"(?<=;)",-1` you can incluse `;`:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sampleContent = "hello ; hai ; come fast ;";
    String SQLScripts[] = sampleContent.split("(?<=;)",-1);
    System.out.println("SQLSCript Length is:"+SQLScripts.length);
    for(int m=0;m<SQLScripts.length-1;m++){
        System.out.println("After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : "+SQLScripts[m]);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
  SQLSCript Length is:4
  After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : hello ;
  After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is :  hai ;
  After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is :  come fast ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex based on lookbehind:

```
String sampleContent="hello ; hai ;  come fast ;";
String SQLScripts[] = sampleContent.split("(?<=;)\\s+");
System.out.println(" SQLSCript Length is:"+SQLScripts.length);
for(int i=0;i<SQLScripts.length;i++){
    System.out.println("After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : "+SQLScripts[i]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
 SQLSCript Length is:3
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : hello ;
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : hai ;
After SQLScripts spliting with semi colon is : come fast ;
```